# How do I make a multi-directional gradient in WPF?

Tags: wpf, colors, gradient, brush

I currently have a gradient set up in XAML as follows:

```xml
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.5"/>
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Canvas.Background>
</Canvas>
```

Result:

[image]

However, this is not what I want to achieve. What I want is to have one gradient transition to a solid colour. Below is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

As one can see from the above image, there is a white-red gradient at the top, and that transitions smoothly to black as it goes down. I have yet to find a way to do this, and this is where I need help. Is there a way to do this? If there is, what is the best way to achieve this (that you know of)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may overlay a second element with a perpendicular LinearGradientBrush that changes opacity:

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas>
        <Canvas.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Canvas.Background>
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas>
        <Canvas.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Canvas.Background>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

I did find an alternative solution while waiting for your answer. I added an `OpacityMask` to the canvas element, then placed a fully black control underneath. Is this an appropriate way of doing it, right?

Comment: All child elements of the Canvas would also be faded out by an OpacityMask. Of course that won't be a problem if it is used as a "background only" element without children. But then a Rectangle would be simpler.